# vb.net apply color to listview subitem

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I need to change the font color in a column in listview. I need to apply this to a subitem in my list. I have created some code to set the color, but not sure how to code the subitem with this information being a fairly new user to vb.net.

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
Dim tmpColor As Color = Color.Red

    While dr.Read()
        ListView1.Items.Add(CDate(dr(4).ToString())).UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
        ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(11).ToString())
        ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(7).ToString())
        with ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(CDbl(dr(5)).ToString("C")).ForeColor = tmpColor

    End With

    ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(14).ToString())
    ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(3).ToString())

End While
```

Comment: This may be of help - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f9a02d/how-to-change-color-and-font-of-each-subitem-in-a-listview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `UseItemStyleForSubItems` property for the given item to false and then perform the corresponding changes to the subitems you want. Sample code:

```
Dim tmpColor As Color = Color.FromName("Blue") 'or just = Color.Blue

While dr.Read()

    ListView1.Items.Add(CDate(dr(4).ToString())).UseItemStyleForSubItems = False

    With ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
        With .Add(dr(11).ToString()))
            .ForeColor = tmpColor 'The font color of this column will be blue
        End With

        .Add(dr(7).ToString())
        .Add(CDbl(dr(5)).ToString("C"))
        .Add(dr(14).ToString())

        With .Add(dr(3).ToString())
            .ForeColor = tmpColor 'The font color of this column will be blue
        End With
    End With

End While
```

Comment: I have updated my original code with the amendments you suggested and then color is still black. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 You are welcome (I was looking at your code and wasn't able to find anything wrong).